# Include pre-defined variable using inline code with knitr

Tags: r, knitr

How does one include a variable using inline expressions with knitr.

For example, this works as expected:

```
A random number from the normal distribution `r rnorm(1)`.
```

But if you want to print a pre-defined string/number:

````
```{r}
company <- "ABC Co"
```

Some text about `r company`
````

Nothing is printed after knitting. Is there something that needs to be wrapped

---

**Update** Session Info, as per request:

```
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_CA.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_CA.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_CA.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_CA.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_CA.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] slidify_0.3.3 knitr_1.2    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.3   evaluate_0.4.3 formatR_0.7    markdown_0.5.4 stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.0    whisker_0.1   
[8] yaml_2.1.7
```

Comment: Works fine for me with knitr 0.9 and knitr 1.2 on Ubuntu.  It's supposed to say "Some text about ABC Co", right?

Comment: You don't have to wrap it in anything?

Comment: I copied and pasted exactly what you provided

Comment: Interesting, it doesn't print anything for me. I figured it out as soon as I typed it out either way.

Comment: Speaking of `print`, it doesn't print if you wrap it in `print`: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/501

Comment: I am having a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478733/inline-knitr-print-code-not-printing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrapping the variable in `I()` makes it work as expected.

````
```{r}
company <- "ABC Co"
```

Some text about `r I(company)`
````

Although not explicit for .Rmd, this is documented here: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/output/

Comment: Interesting. Like @GSee said, I do not need `I()` either; 'r company'  works for me (replace single quotes with backticks -- I cannot type the backticks here). What is your `knitr` version?

Comment: I'm using 1.2. But I'm also using slidify so this could be related to it rather than knitr.

Comment: I tested both `knit()` and `slidify()`. I still did not see any problems with your original example. If `update.packages()` does not work, please post `library(knitr); library(slidify); sessionInfo()`

Comment: I did not see anything wrong in the session info. Please add `knit_hooks$get("inline")` to any code chunks (to print out the `inline` hook) and paste the output.

Comment: function(x) .inline.hook(format_sci(x,"html")) <environment: 0x27123c8>

Comment: I have no idea now. Everything looks OK.