# Inline knitr print code not printing

Tags: r, knitr

How do I fix this?

```
Inline `r 41`. What about `r print(42)`? Finally, `r I(print(43))`.
```

When I run this through knit2html(), it prints 42 and 43 to the R console. The HTML file that's produced is missing the 42.

```
Inline 41. What about ? Finally, 43.
```

I just found this: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md

```
MINOR CHANGES

    for inline R code, the value is returned only if the R code prints a visible value, e.g. \Sexpr{x <- 1} will be empty, and \Sexpr{pi} will return the value of pi
```

I think this change is a mistake. Please revert it. I have a function that does the printing. Do I really need to wrap it in I() every time I use it?

I could wrap the print statements inside the function in I(), but that's a hack and it doesn't even work too well. What if I am using a third party function that does the printing?

Here is what happens when I wrap print statements inside the function in I():

```
my_print = function () {
    I(print(142))
}

my_cat = function () {
    I(cat(143, "\n"))
}
```

Markdown:

````
What `r my_print()` about `r my_cat()` this?

```{r}
my_print()
```

```{r}
my_cat()
```
````

Output:

```
What 142 about this?
my_print()

## [1] 142

## [1] 142

my_cat()

## 143

## list()
```

So this fixes it for inline use, but breaks for chunk use. But only for print. Cat doesn't even work for inline.

Comment: Can you give a more elaborate example of the print statement that your function returns? Why can't you just return a the string instead of printing it?

Comment: I could return a string. But I also want to pass parameters to the print function, so it wouldn't be the same. What if I am using a package that does the printing? It needs to work correctly with knitr.

Comment: It's very hard to give you good advice if you don't provide a clear example. Please a minimal example of such a function with parameters to your example.