# Control digit printing for inline knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I'm working on a knitr project to HTML (at this point). I was trying to control digit printing using the `print(x, digits = 2)` function which worked in the console fine. However, when I knit the markdown it does not produce any inline content. For example:

```
Pi is `r pi`.
Pi printed is `r print(pi, digits = 2)`.
Pi rounded is `r round(pi,2)`.
```

produces the following when knit:

> Pi is 3.1415927. Pi printed is . Pi rounded is 3.14.

The second statement using `print` doesn't include the calculation. As you can see, my solution was to use `round` but I wondered why this is happening or if it is expected behavior. Another solution was to use `options(scipen = 0, digits = 2)` (as on [link](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/output/)) in a code chunk but I wanted to control only a specific part of the output.

Similar, unanswered question: [Inline knitr print code not printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478733/inline-knitr-print-code-not-printing)

Comment: It may be related to the fact that `print` returns the `NULL` object. Maybe `knitr` needs an actual object returned and performs it's own, internal printing. Maybe `formatC(pi, digits=3)` or `sprintf("%0.2f", pi)` will be sufficient?

Comment: Googled this: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/501

Comment: @J_F This confirms what lmo said. For my case I'm not able to simply remove the print command but some alternative functions work instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `print()` does not work has been explained in [#501](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/501). Besides, please note that `print(x)` often returns `invisible(x)`, so the actual value you passed to  **knitr** is still `x`, and `digits = 2` is meaningless. `print()` is typically used only for its *side-effects* (printing in the console/terminal), and it does not modify the value passed to it. To sum it up:

1. `print(x)` returned `invisible(x)`, so **knitr** ignored it;
2. `print(x, digits = 2)` does not round `x` as its returned value, so you cannot get the desired number of digits via `print()`.

`round()`, `formatC()`, and `sprintf()` are all correct ways of formatting numbers.